# ObjectInputStream's readObject() not working

Tags: java, sockets

I am getting an object from the server.
Here is my code:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
in.readObject();

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2303)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2596)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at cs380p6re.TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:29)
```

in.readObject() is on line 29. I know for sure that the server is sending me the object. If I run this with my frinds' laptops, it works. But if I run it using my laptop, it gives me such errors. I've tried both using eclipse and terminal, but i get the same result. Please help.

Comment: To get proper answer it is always good to post minimal but complete code which will let us reproduce your problem ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also explain how are you using/running that code.

Comment: "Reset" means the server refused the connection, usually because no one is listening on that port.

Comment: @markspace No it doesn't. That would cause a `ConnectException`. OP has a connection.

Comment: @OP It doesn't make sense to call `readObject()' without assigning the result to a variable.